# No jdbc driver for mysql 8.0.28

Tags: mysql, jdbc

How to get the JDBC driver for mysql 8.0.28 the [website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) has installer only. Does they removed it? How to get the driver for this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want 8.0.28 (mentioned in the title) or 8.0.29 (mentioned in the body of the question)? Either way, if you *only* want the JAR file, then use the "Platform independent" download option - either from the main download tab or from the archives tab in the link you provided. From there you can download a zip file or a tar file - and the JAR file (the actual driver) will be inside.

Alternatively, use [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java): pick the version you want and either use a Maven POM or just click on the JAR file download link.

Comment: changed the body correctly